# How to differentiate logs that don't have an ID to aggregate them separately on SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a (hypotetical) device that logs consumption events of its batteries. It has a few slots and daily logs the percentage consumed for the battery in each slot. This is what the data looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE batteries
(slot integer, day date, percentage integer);

INSERT INTO batteries
(slot, day, percentage)
VALUES
(0, '2020-05-08', 96),
(0, '2020-05-09', 96),
(0, '2020-05-10', 97),
(0, '2020-05-11', 97),
(0, '2020-05-12', 97),
(0, '2020-05-13', null),
(0, '2020-05-14', 95),
(0, '2020-05-15', 96),
(0, '2020-05-16', null),
(0, '2020-05-17', 1),
(0, '2020-05-18', 2),
(1, '2020-05-08', 10),
(1, '2020-05-09', 10),
(1, '2020-05-10', 10);
```

The log shows that in slot `0`, a battery that was almost completely consumed has been replaced on May 13 by another used battery, which was then replaced on May 16 by a new one. The battery in slot `1` always reported 10% usage.

I need to identify each individual battery, the last value it has reported and the first and last dates it has reported such a value. So this is the output I'm trying to get:

```
slot  min_date      max_date      percentage  sequence
------------------------------------------------------
0     '2020-05-10'  '2020-05-12'  97          0
0     '2020-05-15'  '2020-05-15'  96          1
0     '2020-05-18'  '2020-05-18'  2           2
1     '2020-05-08'  '2020-05-10'  10          0
```

Last known value of battery `0` in slot `0` was `97`, which it reported from May 10 to May 12;

Last known value of battery `1` in slot `0` was `96`, which it reported only on May 15;

Last known value of battery `2` (current) in slot `0` was `2`, which it reported only on May 18;

Last known value of battery `0` (current) in slot `1` was `10`, which it reported from May 08 to May 10.

My main issue here is how to get the min and max date for each battery without having a battery id. In this example, if I group by slot and percentage to get the dates, I'll get the wrong min date on battery `1` of slot `0`, because there was another battery with the same percentage in that slot before.

Is there a way I can get this result on a SQL query, without post-processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the data correctly, you know there is a new battery when the value is `NULL`.  If that is the indication, then you can calculate the sequence by calculating the number of `NULL` values up to each row (using a cumulative sum).

You have one additional step to get the last value and then aggregate:

```
select slot,
       min(day) filter (where percentage = last_percentage),
       max(day), last_percentage,
       sequence
from (select b.*,
             first_value(percentage) over (partition by slot, sequence order by day desc) as last_percentage
      from (select b.*,
                   count(*) filter (where percentage is null) over (partition by slot order by day) as sequence
            from batteries b
           ) b
       where percentage is not null
     ) b
group by slot, sequence, last_percentage
order by slot, sequence;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a4ebbbbadb710ccf88e4724b64fa9f1d) is a db<>fiddle.

In Redshift you just use `case` expressions or booleans:

```
select slot,
       min(case when percentage = last_percentage then day end),
       max(day), last_percentage,
       sequence
from (select b.*,
             first_value(percentage) over (partition by slot, sequence order by day desc) as last_percentage
      from (select b.*,
                   sum( (percentage is null)::int ) over (partition by slot order by day) as sequence
            from batteries b
           ) b
       where percentage is not null
     ) b
group by slot, sequence, last_percentage
order by slot, sequence;
```

Comment: You understood the data correctly, and your answer is flawless. BUT. I should have mentioned that my data is in RedShift, which doesn't have the `filter` clause. I'm struggling to transform this into a `case when`, but I'm not sure it's doable.

Comment: @ramonito_almeida . . . You should tag question your questions correctly.  I updated the answer to be Redshift-compatible.

Comment: Agreed. My bad. Thanks for updating the tag and the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have put some logic as following, which may (or may not) help you to get `min` and `max` date. check [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hTvhYmPVEojqKspg58fD9/0) here.

```
with cte as
(
  select
    *,
    dense_rank() over (partition by percentage order by rnk desc) as nrnk
  from
  (
    select
          *,
          (day - '2000-01-01'::date 
               - row_number() over (partition by percentage order by day)) as rnk
      from batteries
      where percentage is not null  
  ) t   
) 

select
  slot,
  min(day) as min_day,
  max(day) as max_day,
  percentage
from cte
where nrnk = 1    
group by
  slot, 
  percentage, 
  nrnk
```

Output:

```
| slot | min_day    | max_day    | percentage |
| ---- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 0    | 2020-05-17 | 2020-05-17 | 1          |
| 0    | 2020-05-18 | 2020-05-18 | 2          |
| 0    | 2020-05-14 | 2020-05-14 | 95         |
| 0    | 2020-05-15 | 2020-05-15 | 96         |
| 0    | 2020-05-10 | 2020-05-12 | 97         |
| 1    | 2020-05-08 | 2020-05-10 | 10         |
```

Comment: Nice job on calculating the rank by relying on the fact that the status is reported daily. Unfortunately, this is not the case in my real data, and it looks like in oversimplifying the example I created this loophole.
Unfortunately, you removed the `nulls` when doing the calculation, and ended up losing the information of when there is a battery replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This is an iterative process. If you want to do this in SQL, use a recursive query. In order to do so, number your rows per slot first, so as to get easy from one row to the next one

In the recursive part:

1. Compare a rows percentage with the one before and remember thus since when this percentage is current.
2. Whenever you hit a null percentage you get a new battery (increase the battery number).

At last: Show the row with the highest date per slot and battery.

```
with recursive numbered as
(
  select
    slot, day, percentage,
    row_number() over (partition by slot order by day) as rn
  from batteries
)
, cte(slot, battery, min_date, max_date, percentage, rn) as
(
  select slot, 1, day, day, percentage, rn
  from numbered
  where rn = 1
   union all
  select
    n.slot,
    cte.battery + case when n.percentage is null then 1 else 0 end,
    case when n.percentage = cte.percentage then cte.min_date else n.day end,
    n.day,
    n.percentage,
    n.rn
  from cte
  join numbered n on n.slot = cte.slot and n.rn = cte.rn + 1
)
select distinct on (slot, battery)
  slot, min_date, max_date, percentage, battery - 1 as sequence
from cte
order by slot, battery, max_date desc;
```

Result:

```
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| slot |  min_date  |  max_date  | percentage | sequence |
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
|    0 | 2020-05-10 | 2020-05-12 |         97 |        0 |
|    0 | 2020-05-15 | 2020-05-15 |         96 |        1 |
|    0 | 2020-05-18 | 2020-05-18 |          2 |        2 |
|    1 | 2020-05-08 | 2020-05-10 |         10 |        0 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1ee3278d6f020f2d1a61bc93276965f5